# Pressing enter to click on hidden button without using JS on a jsf page?

Tags: jsf

I have a jsf page where I have several 's. When I press enter I want a particular button to be clicked - and this button is hidden. Is there a way to do this without using JS?
I know if i place the button as the first button on the page, it will be clicked by default - but it does not seem to work.

Here is the sample code. I want the "hiddenButton" to be clicked on Enter.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="button1" action="#{bean.action1}" /> 
    <h:commandButton id="button2" action="#{bean.action2}" /> 
    <h:commandButton id="button3" action="#{bean.action3}" />
    <h:commandButton id="hiddenButton" action="#{bean.hiddenAction}" style="display:none;"/> 
<h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a way to do this without using JS?*

Not if you want to support all browsers.

---

> *I know if i place the button as the first button on the page, it will be clicked by default - but it does not seem to work.*

This works only in Firefox, not in Chrome (Webkit) or IE. If you replace `display:none` by `visibility:hidden`, then it'll also work in Chrome, but still not in IE.

So, if you want to support all browsers, JS is your best bet. There may be better solutions depending on the concrete functional requirement, [which you didn't tell anything about in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The actual problem is I want the hidden button clicked, when I press enter.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I only don't understand the problem for which you thought that this is the solution.

Comment: It works with JS. was wondering if this can be done without JS.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Why exactly do you need to invoke a different and hidden action on enter key press instead of just the firstnext button? So, what exactly is the problem for which you thought that invoking a different and hidden action is the solution?

Comment: I have a page where I search by different criteria (by Date, Type and Price). When a user enters something on the <h:inputText> and press enter the corresponding search needs to happen. By default, the first button is clicked (firefox). So my solution was to have a hidden button and based on what field was entered, call the corresponding search method.